# bash_profile open cv and fi error

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0, bash

There are few problems that need to solve. 
first there is an error. -bash: /Users/jay/.bash_profile: line 7: `fi'

second, i am having trouble updating .bash_profile to install opencv.
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/

Here are the code below and please help.

many thanks!

```
# added by Anaconda2 4.2.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/jay/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

  source '/Users/jay/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'
fi
  source '/Users/jay/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
fi

# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f /Users/jay/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc ]; then
  source '/Users/jay/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'
fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f /Users/jay/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc ]; then
  source '/Users/jay/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have `fi` statements without `if` (`fi` is the 'closing' statement for an 'opening' `if`):

```
  source '/Users/jay/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'
fi
  source '/Users/jay/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
fi
```

[bash syntax for `if` statements](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) is e.g.

```
if [ -f /var/log/messages ]; then
    echo "/var/log/messages exists."
fi
```

so for you this may be:

```
if [ -f '/Users/jay/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'];  then
    source '/Users/jay/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'
fi
```

and similar for the next line.

and there is a final `fi` missing at the end of your file.